# Where to put bash-completion scripts from 3rd party programs in Fedora?

Tags: bash, fedora, autocomplete

A piece of software I would like to use, [xsos](https://github.com/ryran/xsos), comes with a bash-completion script.

Where is the correct place to store it on a Fedora system?

Should I create a generic directory in my `$HOME` and then call it from `.bashrc`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the content of the script, it is [indicated in it](https://github.com/ryran/xsos/blob/b393dc08bb234d91779ba781350c5a4c781f0fbf/xsos-bash-completion.bash#L2C1-L2C1) ;-)

```bash
# Save it to: /etc/bash_completion.d/
```

Just for information, on Fedora (38 at least) there is the following directory:

```
~/.bashrc.d/
```

The `.bashrc` sources all files inside:

```bash
# User specific aliases and functions
if [ -d ~/.bashrc.d ]; then
        for rc in ~/.bashrc.d/*; do
                if [ -f "$rc" ]; then
                        . "$rc"
                fi
        done
fi
```

If you want to source a file for everyone on the system, put it in

```
/etc/profile.d/
```

But for your specific question, I think the answer is inside the script itself, as I showed you ;-).